Facing problem with downloading of Google font from next/font
I'm using nextjs 14.2.10 and tried to use
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google';

const inter = Inter({
  subsets: ['latin'],
  weight: ['100', '200', '300', '400', '500', '600', '700', '800', '900'],
  style: ['normal'],
  variable: '--font-inter',
  fallback: ['sans-serif'],
});

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppPropsWithLayout) => {
  const getLayout = (Component as NextPageWithLayout).getLayout || ((page) => page);
  return (
    <main className={`${inter.className}`}>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ErrorBoundary>{getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)}</ErrorBoundary>
      </Provider>
    </main>
  );
};

But I'm getting following compilation error regarding downloading of font. Please help how to resolve?

Retrying 1/3...
The user aborted a request.
Retrying 2/3...
The user aborted a request.
Retrying 3/3...
AbortError: The user aborted a request.
at abort (/Users/shreyak.jain/Documents/Work/test/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/node-fetch/index.js:1:65594)
at EventTarget.abortAndFinalize (/Users/shreyak.jain/Documents/Work/test/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/node-fetch/index.js:1:65814)
at [nodejs.internal.kHybridDispatch] (node:internal/event_target:825:20)
at EventTarget.dispatchEvent (node:internal/event_target:760:26)
at abortSignal (node:internal/abort_controller:370:10)
at AbortController.abort (node:internal/abort_controller:392:5)
at Timeout. (/Users/shreyak.jain/Documents/Work/test/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/font/dist/google/fetch-css-from-google-fonts.js:44:47)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
type: 'aborted'
}
Failed to download Inter from Google Fonts. Using fallback font instead.

I expect to font gets downloaded and work as expected.
